# Is it generally OK to use a Reactive Streams Processor as an event bus?

Tags: rx-java, event-bus, reactive-streams

I started learning about reactive streams because I was curious about this new trend of using RxJava as a replacement for more traditional event buses.  [This blog post](https://lorentzos.com/rxjava-as-event-bus-the-right-way-10a36bdd49ba) is a typical description of how this is done.  If I understand correctly, RxJava 1.x was not strictly an implementation of Reactive Streams, but it was very similar.  Version 2.0 includes some classes that are compliant, or at least pass the TCK, so an updated version of this code may look a little different.

```
public class UserLocationModel {

  private PublishSubject<LatLng> subject = PublishSubject.create();

  public void setLocation(LatLng latLng) {
    subject.onNext(latLng);
  }

  public Observable<LatLng> getUserLocation() {
    return subject;
  }
}
```

In Reactive Streams terminology, I think `subject` is a [`Processor`](http://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.0-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Processor.html), which is both a `Publisher` and a `Subscriber`.

The problem is that calling `onNext` on a `Subscriber` that isn't subscribed to anything would seem to violate the Reactive Streams spec, particularly [rule 1.9](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/blob/master/README.md#1.9).

**Is it merely an implementation detail that this works at all?**  Am I correct in thinking that you cannot generally rely on this working with a compliant Reactive Streams implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Subject`s and `Processor`s of standard RxJava 2 are relaxed so you don't have to call `onSubscribe` on them before calling the other methods. This is partly due to traditionality as 1.x Subjects didn't have an `onSubscribe` and partly due to the fact that RxJava 2 Processors don't coordinate requests between the `Subscriber` side and the `Publisher` side by choice and thus have no use for a `Subscription`.

If you subscribe an RxJava `Processor` any RS compliant `Publisher`, they will appear to request `Long.MAX_VALUE` and relay signals as much as possible. If you subscribe an RS compliant `Subscriber` to RxJava `Processor`s, they will honor the backpressure of those `Subscriber`s and never overflow them, however, the lack of requests may result in individual `MissingBackpressureException` being emitted and the `Subscriber` "thrown" away. There is a custom `Publisher` in the [extensions library](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#multicastprocessor) that does coordinate requests.

> Am I correct in thinking that you cannot generally rely on this working with a compliant Reactive Streams implementation.

There is nothing in the specification and thus not tested in the TCK what should happen with a `Processor` that didn't receive an `onSubscribe` call yet it needed it, therefore, I think this has become an implementation detail.

There are two bigger issues here:

1. Subjects were invented to bridge the imperative world with the reactive world and work nicely in GUI cases and non-backpressured cases as the multicasters of events. In reactive-reactive multicasts, they are better and more direct alternatives, such as `publish(Function)`.
2. Thinking in event bus is a step backwards because you create a single choke point by shoveling in and draining out events on a single "rail". In contrast, design for reactive favors individual and often independent streams where each stream can jump between threads as necessary and perhaps avoid the main thread till the very last moment.